# Hover effect on element is not working in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the color of box2 when I hover over box1 but its not working. please help me why this is not working.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box1,
.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: teal;
  /*   position:relative; */
}

.box2 {
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}

.box1:hover .box2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.box1:hover .box2` targets all elements **within** box1 when it is hovered over.

However, you'd like to make it so it targets elements **next**  to box1. So you can use the `+` symbol instead!

The `+` symbol targets the element after the first element.

So please change it to `.box1:hover + box2`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box1,
.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: teal;
  /*   position:relative; */
}

.box2 {
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}

.box1:hover + .box2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`.box1:hover .box2` indicates the `.box2` selector which is included in `.box1` when hovered. So there is no selector for that.

In your case, you should use `.box1:hover ~ .box2` which indicates the `.box2` selector next to `.box1` selector.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box1, .box2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.box1 {
  background-color: teal;
/*   position:relative; */
}
.box2 {
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}

.box1:hover ~ .box2{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the + selector to access a sibling. Your code was looking for box2 as a child element

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box1,
.box2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: teal;
  /*   position:relative; */
}

.box2 {
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
  left: -50px;
}

.box1:hover + .box2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add  `~` after `hover`

```css
.box1:hover ~ .box2 {
        background-color: green;
      }
```